# changing scroll position after hiding pictures - jQuery

Tags: jquery, scroll, position, fadein

I've got a problem with my code. My page is made of  some sections. In one section there are some full hd jpgs with width 90% . So I dont know their height on different screens. You can see this images after clicking a link and you can hide them after clicking link again. But there is a problem: when you hide them, page is on another section, because pictures took more than 100% height of screen. It's like this:

```
var cos = "2";
$(".section").on("click", ".photo", function() {
    if (cos == "2") {
        $(".pics").fadeIn();
        cos = "1";    
    }
    else {
           $(".pics").hide(); 
    cos = "2";
   }

});
```

[**Fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/z3B5y/)

My question is: how to make that page stay in pisition of this link?

PS. Sorry for my English. I'm from Poland and I'm still not pro in using Eng :p

Answer (score 0):

place

```
 <div class="photo">click me</div>
```

before

```
<div class="pics"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/z3B5y/1/)

Add `id="stick"` for `<div id="stick" class="section" style="background-color: yellow;">`

**css**

```
.fixed {
    position:fixed;
    top:10px;
    left:10px;
    z-index:10;
}
```

**Jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var s = $("#stick");
    var s1 = $(".photo");
    var pos = s.position();                    
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var windowpos = $(window).scrollTop();
        var sheight = pos.top+s.height();
        if ((windowpos >= pos.top) && (windowpos <= sheight)) {
            s1.addClass("fixed");
        } else {
            s1.removeClass("fixed"); 
        }
    });

    $(".pics").hide();
    var cos = "2";
    $(".section").on("click", ".photo", function() {
        if (cos == "2") {
            $(".pics").fadeIn();
            cos = "1";    
        }
        else {
               $(".pics").hide(); 
        cos = "2";
       }

    });
});
```